# Modificar registros desde un formulario en una web ASP.NET Core MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tengo una web MVC en la que dispongo de un formulario que crea un proyecto con más de 40 campos y los introduce en una tabla de un SQL Server, mediante Entity Framework. Eso funciona correctamente.

Para Modificar, hago un listado de proyectos y pulsando sobre ellos puedo modificarlos. Se abre una vista de un formulario (Similar al de crear Proyectos) que es llamado desde el siguiente controlador **HttpGet EditarProyecto**.  Cuando se abre, aparece el formulario con sus campos rellenos perfectamente con los datos existentes que hay en la base de datos.  Hasta ahí, también funciona correctamente.

```
[HttpGet] 
public async Task<IActionResult> EditarProyecto(int id)
{
    var proyecto = await context.Proyectos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);

    if (proyecto is null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Noencontrado", "Index");
    }
    return await Task.Run(() => View(proyecto));
}

[HttpPost] 
public async Task<IActionResult> EditarProyecto(Proyecto proyectoEditar)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(proyectoEditar);
    }
    var proyecto = await context.Proyectos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == proyectoEditar.Id);
    if (proyecto is null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Noencontrado", "Index");
    }
    //proyecto = proyectoEditar;    
    context.Proyectos.Update(proyecto); 
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();  
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}
```

El problema viene que cuando pulso el botón del formulario tras hacer algún cambio en alguno de los campos. (Se ejecuta el **HttpPost EditarProyecto** )

Coloco un punto de interrupción en la línea de SaveChangesAsync() para ver valores

Entonces:

- Si lo dejo tal cual está el código, no me da error, pero no me hace nada . El valor de la variable "`**proyecto**`" aparece con los datos que hay en la db sin modificar, no con los del formulario modificado y el parámetro "**`proyectoEditar`**" no me deja seleccionarlo, por lo que no veo su valor. Es como si no existiera, por eso no le pasa el parámetro.
- Si habilito la línea "`proyecto = proyectoEditar;`"  dejando el código de esta forma:

  ```
        proyecto = proyectoEditar;
        context.Proyectos.Update(proyecto); 
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();   
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
  ```

Al pulsar para enviar el formulario, me aparece el siguiente error en en navegador:

**InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Proyecto' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.**

Por el contrario, si escribo campo por campo y desabilito la línea con el `Update`, funciona correctamente, hace el cambio en aquellos campos que se han escrito en el código, pero no en los otros, pero claro, no voy a escribir más de 40 campos en el controlador, además, si el día de mañana hago un cambio en el nombre de un campo o añado o quito un campo, debo modificar el formulario, el controlador, el ViewModel, la entidad...

```
        proyecto.Titulo = proyectoEditar.Titulo;
        proyecto.URL = proyectoEditar.URL
        .

        .Todos los campos aquí...
        .           

        //context.Proyectos.Update(proyecto); 
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Seguro que es una tontería, pero no se verlo y me he quedado atascado.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba  context.Proyectos.Update(proyectoEditar);

Comment: No funciona tampoco.

Comment: En tu respuesta tienes exactamente lo que te dije context.Proyectos.Update(proyectoEditar);

Comment: Sí Yussef, tienes razón, pero me refiero a que además había que eliminara la línea           var proyecto = await context.Proyectos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == proyectoEditar.Id);

Answer (score 0):

Ya está resuelto. Me han echado una mano el profe de Udemy.
Estaba cargando la entidad, y luego, a través de otro objeto, intentaba actualizarla, algo que es imposible.

Tengo que remover la línea `var proyecto` y sustituir proyecto por `ProyectoEdirtar`

```
[HttpPost] 
public async Task<IActionResult> EditarProyecto(Proyecto proyectoEditar)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(proyectoEditar);
    }

        // var proyecto = await context.Proyectos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == proyectoEditar.Id);
        if (proyectoEditar is null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Noencontrado", "Index");
        }
        //proyecto = proyectoEditar;    
        context.Proyectos.Update(proyectoEditar); 
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();  
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
```